# Is it posible to access a javascript which resides in a script file from a iframe

Tags: asp.net, html, iframe

i want to access a javascript function which resides in a script file from   another page with iframe.
my sample code :

Page from which javascript need to be accessed.

```
 <iframe id="FRAMESET" src="default.htm" width="0%" height="0%">
        <p>
            Your browser does not support iframes.
        </p>
    </iframe>
```

default.htm

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link href="Scripts/main.js" type="text/javascript" />
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
function helloWorld() {
    alert("hello World");
}
```

i want to access this function on main page. i tried document.getElementById('FRAMESET').contentWindow.helloWorld(); but gave me error "that document.getElementById('FRAMESET').contentWindow.helloWorld();" is not a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible. You can do this in the page that contains the frame:

```
document.getElementById('FRAMESET').contentWindow.helloWorld();
```

Comment: thanx for the quick reply. i tried this but its not working .its giving me document.getElementById('FRAMESET').contentWindow.helloWorld(); is not a function

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. All browsers (IE, FF, Chrome) now prevent js accessing to iframe content. Why don't you just load main.js into the main page?

Comment: Actually you can access iframe content, as long as the iframe resides in the same domain.